# Github - Is it possible to create 'read only' OAuth Token?

Tags: git, github, oauth, version-control

I'm trying to create a read-only token for github that will allow me to read raw files using AJAX request, but will not allow others to edit the code.

Seems like the only option is to create a Token which will have read & write access.

Do you know if that's possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's not possible. You can only create a read and write token.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate branch for it and that use the Github build in feature for restricting permissions to a given branch.

https://help.github.com/articles/enabling-branch-restrictions/
[image]